# MongoDB aggregate $sort opration question

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregate, explain

**In MongoDB v4.2 with data as below and without other index except _id:**

```
db.surveys.insertMany([
    {_id:"A1", from_uid:NumberInt(100), to_uid:NumberInt(200), time:NumberInt(1234)}, 
    {_id:"A2", from_uid:NumberInt(100), to_uid:NumberInt(300), time:NumberInt(1231)}, 
    {_id:"A3", from_uid:NumberInt(300), to_uid:NumberInt(200), time:NumberInt(1230)}, 
    {_id:"A4", from_uid:NumberInt(100), to_uid:NumberInt(201), time:NumberInt(1231)}, 
    {_id:"A5", from_uid:NumberInt(100), to_uid:NumberInt(202), time:NumberInt(1235)}, 
])
```

**Then with two operation statement with explain:**

```
db.surveys.aggregate([{"$match":{"from_uid":100}},{"$sort":{"time":-1}}]).explain(true)  
db.surveys.find({"from_uid":100}).sort({"time":-1}).explain(true)
```

**The question is:**

why statement 1 explain result in "Sorted in Memory" is false while statement 2 is true.

**Thanks for your answer.**

What I thought before is such 2 statement explain result in "Sorted in Memory" is true.

Comment: Did you try the same with the current version of MongoDB? Version 4.2 is almost EoL.

Comment: MongoDB server version 6.0.6 shows [`"usedDisk": false`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8_S-s-l6y3z).

Comment: Where are you seeing this `Sorted in Memory` information? Without knowing what it represents I'm not sure we can help answer the question. If you only have the `_id` index then both operations must perform a 'blocking sort' since there is no index available to provide it. How that information gets represented outside of the database is unclear and the responsibility of whatever software is displaying the information.